# Daily Oracle SQL insert from email

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an excel file I get as an email everyday is there anyway to run a script on it so it automatically adds that data to the SQL database (oracle). I dont even know where to start. The excel files different columns will be different rows in the table (Based on the date) but thats not as important.

Basically, how do I achieve this task?

Comment: Depends on how you want to automate it.  Importing from Excel into Oracle is the easy part, especially if you can use any programming language in between.  (Though the part about columns in the file mapping to rows in the database sounds a bit strange...)  Java would be a good place to start for Oracle interactions.  The question is, what would initiate this automation?  You can save the file and run an application easily, but that's still fairly manual.  Maybe save the file to a location being monitored by a process?  Or have the process poll the mail server for messages to parse?

Comment: Yeah, I have no clue about the last two things you said haha. I think if i can figure out a way to monitor my email and then run my script to insert the file on that. then i think it should work but where do I even begin? any suggestions? I am so new to this

Comment: Start with the language (such as Java) and break up the problem into individual elements of functionality, each of which can be Googled and attempted and tested.  Things like: 1) Read an Excel file in Java, 2) Write to Oracle in Java, 3) Read email (POP3?  IMAP?) in Java, 4) Schedule Java application to run periodically, etc.  The overall goal may be very custom, but each individual element of functionality is likely very common and many examples can be found online.

Comment: Sweet! will do sir, thanks!

Comment: Java seems to be an overkill. Try scripting languages.

Comment: A lot of your options for making the email receipt kick off an action depend on what OS you are running. On UNIX systems this is pretty trivial so you don't need a scheduled job/cron. There are also ways to do this on Windows systems. There a ton of different ways to handle this but David gave you good advice on breaking the task down into steps to make life easier